# Install Chrome/Chromium extension disabled by default

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I found a useful Chrome extension that I will use only in very few sites, so I was planning to use the "When you click the extension" feature for security and performance reasons:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

But after install I noticed that it was activated in all my open tabs beforehand, as the default is "On all sites". Is there a way to have the "When you click the extension" as the default after extension install?